# File not found at absolute path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that creates a file and moves it via `os.rename`, The file is generated while the script is running, however when I go to open the file I get

```
os.rename(str(PATH_TO_PROGRAM)+str("Outputs/important_output.txt"), str(args['output_dir'])+ str("important_output.txt"))

with open(str(args['output_dir'])+str("important_output.txt), "r") as infile:
     do stuff
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "my_script.py", line 2863, in <module>
    with open(str(args['output_dir'])+str("important_output.txt"), "r") as infile:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/c/Users/jaysp/Desktop/new/important_output.txt'
```

I'm not sure why the file isn't found. It is generated while the script is running. I see it in the directory I copy it to. If it helps, I run the script from Windows Subsytem Linux and I edit my code in VSCode.

Comment: well it's clear /mnt/c/Users/jaysp/Desktop/new/important_output.txt does not exist or you don't have permission on that directory, type ls -lh /mnt/c/Users/jaysp/Desktop/new and check if you have execution privileges (+x)

Comment: @Mr.bug the permissions are -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: type file /mnt/c/Users/jaysp/Desktop/new/important_output.txt and check if you have a typo

Comment: @Mr.bug I copied directly from the FileNotFoundError and  I get this: /mnt/c/Users/jaysp/Desktop/new/important_output.txt: ASCII text

Comment: Update: I used the script on another computer and it worked. What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try using os.path.join to join paths

```
input = os.path.join(PATH_TO_PROGRAM, "Outputs/important_output.txt")
output = os.path.join(args['output_dir'], "important_output.txt")
os.rename(input, output)

with open(output, 'r') as infile:
  ...
```